# How to delete row from table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a table view, data were retrieved from database and display in the table rows.

I have a remove button at the top navigation bar from removing table row.

When button is tapped,  a red circle delete icon will appear.

After I select delete, it gave me and error call "Program received signal SIGABRT" at the [tableViewDelete rows......]
This is my code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
      {              
           Object = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           [ClassA ClassAMethod:[appDelegate getDBPath] :Object.ID];
           [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      }   
}
```

How do I remove a row from the table view?

Does anybody have any ideas or has anybody else achieved anything similar?

Thanks

Comment: There's some information missing here: what exactly does `ClassAMethod` do, does it delete the appropriate object and is it removed from the local `array`? Anyway you might also check for zombie objects.

Comment: is there necessary requirement for delete button in navigation bar...?bcoz in table view you have already inbuilt delete button...and what is the use of this line  [ClassA ClassAMethod:[appDelegate getDBPath] :Object.ID];?

Comment: ClassA ClassAMethod is a method to delete data in my database.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this line:

```
[ClassA ClassAMethod:[appDelegate getDBPath] :Object.ID];
```

deletes your object from database, while table is filled from some `array` instance - you need to delete an object from that array as well to maintain data integrity (`array` must be `NSMutableArray` instance):

```
Object = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[ClassA ClassAMethod:[appDelegate getDBPath] :Object.ID];
// Add the following line
[array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath:row];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: I have added the following line but still having the same problem.

Comment: post your crash log it help us too give reliable answer

Answer (score 1):

try this code in editing delegate method of `tableview`:--

```
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)

  {
    [[self displayedObjects] removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    //  Animate deletion
    NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
    [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 }
```

i hope this can solve your problem

Comment: Remember when you do this, to remove from your datasource, the data that was for the row you are visually deleting: otherwise a reload data will just draw the row again.